# Как обратиться к значению в последнем массиве?

Tags: php, laravel

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста как в моем случае обратиться к значению в последнем массиве?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можно взять значение по ключу -  `echo $array[1]['end']` или всегда брать последнее значение в массиве  `echo end($array[1])`

Comment: `end($array)['end']`  но выгядит стремно :) `$last = end($array); echo $last['end']`

Answer (score 2):

Вам необходимо использовать функцию [`array_key_last()`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-key-last.php). В которую передаете исходный массив и на выходе вы получите индекс последнего ключа в массиве. В вашем случае будет примерно так если предположить что в `$array` лежит исходный массик:

```
echo $array[array_key_last($array)]["end"];
```

Так как `array_key_last` доступна только в `php 7.3` и выше, то можно для себя написать ее аналог:

```
function array_key_last( $array ) {
    $key = NULL;

    if ( is_array( $array ) ) {

        end( $array );
        $key = key( $array );
    }

    return $key;
}
```

Comment: Необходимо уточнить что функция `array_key_last` доступна начиная с __php7.3__.